# Encrypting smarty tpl module file in WHMCS

Tags: php, encryption, smarty, whmcs, ioncube

I am trying to encrypt a tpl file with ionCube in my module in WHMCS without modifying WHMCS smarty.class file. Anyone have any idea how can I do that?

For further information see http://www.ioncube.com/sa_encoder.php?page=smarty_patch

Answer (score 2):

Of course you need to have ionCube Php Encoder, you need to create project, add files and then in GUI in `Project settings -> Source` you should right click on your TPL file and select "Encrypt non-PHP file".  There is no way you can do it without applying Smarty patch as in ionCube documentation.

You can also extend Smarty class.

For **Smarty 2** the code will be simple:

```
<?php

class MyTemplate extends Smarty {

// Replacement function for _read_file() in Smarty.class.php to add support
// for reading both ionCube encrypted templates and plain text templates.
// Smarty.class.php must be encoded by the creator of the templates for
// ioncube_read_file() to decode encrypted template files

    function _read_file($filename)
    {
        $res = false;

        if (file_exists($filename)) {
            if (function_exists('ioncube_read_file')) {
                $res = ioncube_read_file($filename);
                if (is_int($res)) $res = false;
            }
            else if ( ($fd = @fopen($filename, 'rb')) ) {
                $res = ($size = filesize($filename)) ? fread($fd, $size) : '';
                fclose($fd);
            }
        }

        return $res;
    }    
}
```

and you should create object of this class to use modified code.

For **Smarty 3** it's a bit more complex.

You need to create `MyFileResource` class as below:

```
<?php
//MyFileResource.php    

class MyFileResource extends Smarty_Internal_Resource_File {

    /**
     * Load template's source from file into current template object
     *
     * @param  Smarty_Template_Source $source source object
     * @return string                 template source
     * @throws SmartyException        if source cannot be loaded
     */
    public function getContent(Smarty_Template_Source $source)
    {       
        if ($source->timestamp) {                                    

            if (file_exists($source->filepath) && function_exists('ioncube_read_file')) {
                $res = ioncube_read_file($source->filepath);
                if (is_int($res)) {
                    $res = false;
                }
                return $res;                  
            }
            else {
                return file_get_contents($source->filepath); 
            }                                
        }

        if ($source instanceof Smarty_Config_Source) {
            throw new SmartyException("Unable to read config {$source->type} '{$source->name}'");
        }
        throw new SmartyException("Unable to read template {$source->type} '{$source->name}'");
    }

}
```

And in place where you created Smarty object add some code.

Assume you created Smarty object this way:

```
require '../libs/Smarty.class.php';

$smarty = new Smarty;
```

You should change it into:

```
require '../libs/Smarty.class.php';

require('MyFileResource.php');

$smarty = new Smarty;

$smarty->registerResource('file', new MyFileResource());
```

This way each time you read templates from files you use your MyFileResource class. I haven't tested this code but it should work. Depending on your settings it's possible you will need to remove all your compiled template files to regenerate them again.

Comment: but in the smarty.class file you have to modify _read_file(), and i dont want to do that, check this link for farther information : http://www.ioncube.com/sa_encoder.php?page=smarty_patch

Comment: Marcin's solution is neat. Unlike with encoded files where the processing is transparent, you have to modify the routine that reads the template because otherwise the decryption cannot happen.

Answer (score 1):

You can encrypt the template files using the non-PHP file encryption feature, but the smarty engine needs to be modified in order to handle the decryption. Without doing so you will just see encrypted contents displayed. Use the ioncube_read_file() API function for this, which will seamlessly handle encrypted and non-encrypted files. Note that the file calling the function must be encoded as there would be no point in having an unprotected file calling a decryption routine.

Comment: But in this case he will modify Smarty class and he don't want to do it as in question

Comment: The smarty engine *needs* to be modified, which is what the answer is saying, and as the question suggests that it is merely a desire rather than a requirement, the answer is valid. Better that he realises this now than end up in hospital from bashing his head against a brick wall. Alternatively he could choose a different template engine, or incorporate a second copy of smarty local to his module so that it is the smarty copy that he modifies and not the WHMCS smarty.

Comment: Actually i started to bash my head it was a long week, but if i want to create my local copy of smarty how can i extend smarty.class and override the _read_file function from the module?

Comment: I've added example for Smarty 2 and Smarty 3 to my answer