# Not able to decode ionCube encoded Smarty(3.1.18) Template files

Tags: php, smarty, smarty3, ioncube

I have used ionCube(ver. 8.3) to encrypt .tpl,.php files including smarty library files, I am able to encode them successfully with all Obfuscation options checked and able to generate Key file also. But when I try to open my index.php page it gives me following error ...

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'LogicException' with message 'Function 'smartyAutoload' not found (function 'smartyAutoload' not found or invalid function name)' in C:\cc\htdocs\App_Encode\Smarty\libs\Smarty.class.php:0 Stack trace: #0 C:\cc\htdocs\App_Encode\Smarty\libs\Smarty.class.php(0): obfuscated #1 C:\cc\htdocs\App_Encode\index_standard_creation.php(0): unknown() #2 {main} thrown in C:\cc\htdocs\App_Encode\Smarty\libs\Smarty.class.php on line 0

The patch which is provided by ionCube is for Smarty 2.*
 ..since I am using **Smarty 3.1.18** version and **PHP Ver. 5.5**...

I am not able to understand where problem lies as I am new to PHP programming. 
I have tried following patch in getContent() function in \libs\plugins\smarty_internal_resource_file.php ..But it's no use :(

```
public function getContent(Smarty_Template_Source $source)
{
   if ($source->timestamp) {
        if (function_exists('ioncube_read_file')) {
            return ioncube_read_file($source->filepath);
        } else {
            return file_get_contents($source->filepath);
        }
    }
    if ($source instanceof Smarty_Config_Source) {
        throw new SmartyException("Unable to read config {$source->type} '{$source->name}'");
    }
    throw new SmartyException("Unable to read template {$source->type} '{$source->name}'");
}
```

Please help me out!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Encrypting smarty tpl module file in WHMCS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24171753/encrypting-smarty-tpl-module-file-in-whmcs)

Answer (score 1):

You've used the good patch for Smarty 3 from http://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?t=20562

You must also encode Smarty, or at least the patched file, as ioncube_read_file() can only be used in an encoded file (in this scenario it would be pointless to have a decrypt routine in a non-encoded file). ioncube_read_file() will return an error code as an integer instead of the file contents as a string if there is an error, so you could extend the patch to test for that and log the error code somewhere. The error codes also exist as constants defined by the ionCube Loader, and the codes and constants are documented in the User Guide PDF.